# Pi 2B won't update TeamViewer

Tags: pi-2, raspbian-jessie, update, rpi-update

I've recently tried to log into my Raspberry Pi (2B with 1GB running Jessie) using TeamViewer and found that my TV software is out of date. I needed to update TV to version 14. When I downloaded **download link removed** from their website to my RPi. I'm no great user of the Linux, so first I tried double-clicking on the .deb file to install. I got an error that says "Failed to install file. An unspecified transaction error has occurred. More information is available in the detailed report." I'm not sure where to find that report.

Then I tried to run system updates first to see if that was the problem.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo reboot
```

That took a long time, but eventually everything was updated. I then tried a command line installation using

```
sudo dpkg -i /home/pi/Desktop/teamviewer-host_14.7.1965_armhf.deb
```

but that returned the same error.

Is there something I'm doing incorrectly, or is my system harboring a gremlin somewhere? Any advice would be most welcome.

Comment: Do **NOT** post questions with a link to download files. Include a link to the source.

Comment: NOTE Jessie is **obsolete**. It is unlikely anyone still has matching .deb files.

Comment: "Obsolete" is at best a wishy-washy term here.  Jessie is no longer being updated, but the [repo is still online](http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/dists/jessie/) and I am sure there are plenty of Pis around that still use it *on purpose* in settings where someone wishes to freeze a system as is.  There's also no reason to believe that "it is unlikely anyone still has matching .deb files"; it is only a handful of years and not decades.

Comment: the following operating systems are supported: Debian 9 (incl. Raspbian)

Comment: Here is one thing that I noticed, based on my knowledge (correct me if I'm wrong), you can't install armhf. The raspberry pi architecture is arm64. You are trying to install an armhf deb file when you should be installing an arm64 file. I'm unsure if armhf is the same as arm64, but I'm just mentioning it if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This could be happening if the file permission has some sort of error?
Redowload the file or just double click the file and see what happens

Comment: I've downloaded it several times but it always gives the same resulting error. I've also checked the file permissions and set them to "anyone" but that didn't change anything either. Any idea where this report file would be located?